# Select last 2 records each time based on the record previously accessed records from the in Sql

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I have `Message` table

```
DDL

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Message](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Message] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Message] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

DML

INSERT [dbo].[Message] ([ID], [Message], [DateCreated]) VALUES (1, N'M1', CAST(0x0000A7F400D63BC0 AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Message] ([ID], [Message], [DateCreated]) VALUES (2, N'M2', CAST(0x0000A7F400E6B680 AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Message] ([ID], [Message], [DateCreated]) VALUES (3, N'M3', CAST(0x0000A7F500D63BC0 AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Message] ([ID], [Message], [DateCreated]) VALUES (4, N'M3', CAST(0x0000A7F600D63BC0 AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Message] ([ID], [Message], [DateCreated]) VALUES (5, N'M3', CAST(0x0000A7F700D63BC0 AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Message] ([ID], [Message], [DateCreated]) VALUES (6, N'M3', CAST(0x0000A7F800D63BC0 AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Message] ([ID], [Message], [DateCreated]) VALUES (7, N'M3', CAST(0x0000A7F900D63BC0 AS DateTime))
GO
```

Table `Message`:

```
ID | Message | DateCreated 
1  | M1      | 2017-09-20 13:00:00
2  | M2      | 2017-09-20 14:00:00 
3  | M3      | 2017-09-21 13:00:00
4  | M3      | 2017-09-22 13:00:00
5  | M3      | 2017-09-23 13:00:00
6  | M3      | 2017-09-24 13:00:00
7  | M3      | 2017-09-25 13:00:00
```

I have limited no of rows to be accessed , each time 2 rows.But based on number of row accessed , want to get next 2 rows.

For example:

1) 0 row accessed and get 2 rows:

```
ID | Message | DateCreated 
6  | M3      | 2017-09-24 13:00:00
7  | M3      | 2017-09-25 13:00:00
```

2) 2 rows accessed and now get next 2 rows:

```
ID | Message | DateCreated 
4  | M3      | 2017-09-22 13:00:00
5  | M3      | 2017-09-23 13:00:00
```

3) 4 rows accessed and now get next 2 rows:

```
ID | Message | DateCreated 
2  | M2      | 2017-09-20 14:00:00 
3  | M3      | 2017-09-21 13:00:00
```

so on.

I may think of left join with itself and then use sub-query. But I m lost somewhere with my idea.

I may in other words as

```
select top 2 rows 
from   message 
where  ID not in (select * 
                  from   message 
                  where  rows already accessed ) 
order  by ID desc;
```

Its like pagination where I saw 2 records on each page. Unfortunately I will not provide the page number , instead I may say I have accessed rows with `ID` `7, 6` . Next two rows will be with `ID` `5, 4` and so on.

Comment: Please, try to clarify it.  It is not clear how do you access to this rows.

Comment: Please, check again. I have added more explanation @McNets

Comment: Give us DDL (`CREATE TABLE...`), DML (`INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (...`), the result you want and the logic you used to get it. Your attempts at solving the problem also.

Comment: @Vérace I am stuck with the fact that I want to access next 2 rows based on previously accessed row.I m in this logic.and so I asked here

Comment: Maybe you're looking at some sort of tree type structure - using [WITH RECURSIVE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood it would work as a pagination, and the params you would control on the app side anyways. I'd would the following:

@SQL2012:

```
SELECT [ID]
     , [message]
     , DateCreated
FROM [message]
ORDER BY ID DESC
OFFSET 1 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is solution for your case.

```
SELECT TOP 2 *
FROM [dbo].[Message]
WHERE ID < (SELECT ISNULL(MIN(ID),2147483647) FROM [dbo].[Message] WHERE <predicate>)
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

For example we can use `DateCreated` column to filter rows and check examples which you provided.

1. 0 row accessed and get 2 rows:

   ```
   SELECT TOP 2 *
   FROM [dbo].[Message]
   WHERE ID < (SELECT ISNULL(MIN(ID),2147483647) FROM [dbo].[Message] WHERE DateCreated > '20170930')
   ORDER BY ID DESC
   ```
2. 4 rows accessed and now get next 2 rows:

   ```
   SELECT TOP 2 *
   FROM [dbo].[Message]
   WHERE ID < (SELECT ISNULL(MIN(ID),2147483647) FROM [dbo].[Message] WHERE DateCreated > '20170924')
   ORDER BY ID DESC
   ```
3. 0 row accessed and get 2 rows:

   ```
   SELECT TOP 2 *
   FROM [dbo].[Message]
   WHERE ID < (SELECT ISNULL(MIN(ID),2147483647) FROM [dbo].[Message] WHERE DateCreated > '20170922')
   ORDER BY ID DESC
   ```

Magic number is the maximum of `INT` data type to manage no rows returned scenario.